# subset data en bucle for R

Tags: r, loops

Estoy haciendo un script en R donde un bucle for itera sobre un string vector llamado iter. El siguiente código funciona y genera una variable llamada como el valor que toma iter en ese momento (i) que contiene el filtrado e un dataframe según i.

```
for ( i in iter) {
  assign(i, subset(out,TestId==paste0(i) & AddId=="Curva_F_Cor"))
}
```

El problema viene cuando quiero obtener una columna concreta de la variable que he creado dentro del bucle for con el siguiente código:

```
for ( i in iter) {
  assign(i, subset(out,TestId==paste0(i) & AddId=="Curva_F_Cor"))
  assign(paste0(i,".mu"), i[,"mu.spline"])
}
```

Resultado en este error:

> ```
> Error in i[, "mu.spline"] : incorrect number of dimensions
> ```

Si pruebo esto, el codigo si que funciona, el problema lo tengo al obtener la columna mu.spline de esta manera, aunque hecho manualmente si que funciona

```
for ( i in iter) {
  assign(i, subset(out,TestId==paste0(i) & AddId=="Curva_F_Cor"))
  i
  assign(paste0(i,".mu"), "hola")
}
```

Que puede estar mal?

Gracias

Editado** OS dejo un dput() de mis datos:

```
structure(list(TestId = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L), .Label = c("Comb1", 
"Comb2", "COD1", "COD2", "COD3", "COD4", "COD5", 
"COD6", "COD7", "COD8", "COD9", "COD10", "COD11", 
"COD12", "COD13", "COD14", "Pat"), class = "factor"), 
    mu.spline = c(0.156373645710651, 0.128179004733465, 0.133922208832118, 
    0.0968325365246728, 0.112497378553166, 0.108787192266453, 
    0.110192954818258, 0.121005105680758, 0.0980394197157738, 
    0.138420857616108, 0.127789639429687, 0.128560390185466, 
    0.110549423439033, 0.108320566548023, 0.098918312107995, 
    0.0828284492044932, 0.104197889210497, 0.122413067260436, 
    0.100261893863431, 0.0938211089313908, 0.0950013179641027, 
    0.145680825059066, 0.139104408376977, 0.126037019624304, 
    0.126708418382696, 0.129821223842992, 0.136480998324424, 
    0.13593684872676, 0.139066913195263, 0.148222162331793, 0.1063086971118, 
    0.167178433353777, 0.0999504815546864, 0.159110219357191, 
    0.125081233896366, 0.163966026506179, 0.15029944955429, 0.116975580695436, 
    0.15276496804095, 0.155339014181045, 0.112171217970295, 0.120104234834245, 
    0.133373734309075, 0.175784287024805, 0.133626401899954, 
    0.140297143337283, 0.0863206151811713, 0.170070971923806, 
    0.152896880973888, 0.10553437562759, 0.124122727198564, 0.163571762302165, 
    0.151047108367937, 0.131416085292366, 0.152515440225195, 
    0.139308623745812, 0.146009754853497, 0.170825235429307, 
    0.147466868348918, 0.126623691613807, 0.147114348605148, 
    0.141084369853073, 0.153670399861141, 0.162948873362462, 
    0.131121302899353, 0.146421599771427, 0.135166111999851, 
    0.157495164357944, 0.126927329131488, 0.159831796004744, 
    0.146936913846553, 0.12183336770971, 0.136669798817364, 0.152333836640196, 
    0.138055091325892)), .Names = c("TestId", "mu.spline"), row.names = c("76", 
"77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", 
"88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", 
"99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", 
"108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", 
"117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", 
"126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", 
"135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", 
"144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sin una muestra de tus datos es un poco difícil encontrar ayudarte, podrías usar `dput()` con unas cuantas filas para que sea un ejemplo reproducible. En todo caso, en vez que utilizar `i[,"mu.spline"]` podrías llamar esa columna con el índice que le corresponde. Por ejemplo, `i[,12]`. Así evitas el uso de etiquetas.

Comment: Probaré lo del indice! Os he dejado un dput de mis datos solo con la columna de interés. He leidio mucho sobre la función `lapply()` pero no la he conseguido aplicar con exito en este caso..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la segunda línea llamas a `i[,"mu.spline"])`, siendo que el objeto `i` no existe, lo utilizaste para crear objetos con nombres en función del vector `iter` en base a la posición `i`. Una solución práctica es utilizar un objeto temporal dentro del bucle para poder extraer las variables necesarias sin problema. Por ejemplo:

```
for(i in iter){
  temp <- subset(out,TestId==paste0(i))
  assign(i, temp)
  assign(paste0(i,".mu"), temp[,"mu.spline"])
}
```

Con esta leve modificación del código no tendrás problemas, luego lo puedes eliminar de ser necesario para ahorrar memoria en el espacio de trabajo.

Considera utilizar este esquema dentro de los bucles para evitar errores con los nombres de objetos creados dentro del mismo bucle. También puedes crear una lista vacía previo a la ejecución del bucle e ir almacenando los resultados en la lista. Pero en este caso, la opción de utilizar una elemento temporal es la más razonable y ligera.

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora entiendo el problema que tenia :)